# Using BiFunction in place of a Comparator does not work

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

While initializing collections like `TreeMap`, `TreeSet`, etc. We can add our custom comparator.
The code looks something like:

```
Map<Integer, String> map1 = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        return x-y;
    }
});
```

Now, we can make replace this anonymous implementation with a lambda expression. The code would look like:

```
Map<Integer, String> map2 = new TreeMap<>((x,y) -> x-y);
```

Java-8 allows you to store lambda expressions in a variable through [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). So, I modified the above code to the following:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> myComparator = (x,y) -> x-y;
Map<Integer, String> map3 = new TreeMap<>(myComparator);
```

But this last attempt did not work! It gave the following error:

> Cannot infer type arguments for TreeMap<>

Why did it fail to resolve types in the last example?

Note: To confirm that this is not an IDE bug, I performed a raw compile using `javac` and it still gave the same error.

Comment: Couldn't you declare your lambda function as `Comparator<Integer> myComparator = (x,y) -> x-y;` instead of `BiFunction`? Since `Comparator` is explicitly the type the `TreeMap` constructor requires.

Comment: I get a *"cannot resolve constructor ...."*.

Comment: @luk2302, which version of java are you using?

Comment: @khelwood that works!!. But unfortunately does not resolve the question.

Comment: @AdityaGupta 1.8.0_131 - "no suitable constructor found for ..." is the actual output, the other one is generated by IntelliJ it seems.

Comment: Do you know what a “functional interface” is? It is *not* an interface required to be in the package `java.util.function`. `Comparator` is already a functional interface. That’s why you can use a lambda expression where a `Comparator` is required, like with `new TreeMap<>((x,y) -> x-y)`. What do you hope to gain from using `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` instead of `Comparator<Integer>`? Besides that, *don’t use minus as comparator function*. Minus can overflow. And anyway, `Comparator.naturalOrder()` is already suitable to this task. (Or just create the `TreeMap` without a comparator)

Comment: @luk2302 Try [this](https://gist.github.com/adityarar/58a45a92a08ac81bdadd2d87de730e01)

Comment: @Holger, I was testing out lambda expressions which could be used as comparators at runtime. `Comparator.naturalOrder()` is good advice, but not all implementations will be available in `Comparator`.

Comment: Regardless of which logic you implement, stay away from using minus. There is `Integer.compare(int,int)` doing the right thing, but usually, when you end up comparing two `int` values, you can use either `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, `Comparator.reverseOrder​()`, `Comparator.comparingInt​(…)`, or a combination of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the lambda expression seems the same, the [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) is not the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) therefore you cannot interchange them.

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = (x,y) -> x - y;
Map<Integer, String> map3 = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```

Let's take a look deeper into these interfaces and implement them using an anonymous class:

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        return x - y;
    }
};

BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> biFun = new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(final Integer x, final Integer y) {
        return x - y;
    }
};
```

The difference is also the name of the method. [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) expects [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in its constructor because its internal implementation will call `compare` according to the contract with [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

By the way, the [`BinaryOperator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) results in the same lambda expression as well.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply because the `TreeMap` constructor expects a `Comparator<Integer>` rather than a `BiFunction`.

With writing `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> myComparator = ...` you explicitly say to the compiler that the variable is of that type. This prevents the compiler from infering the type required to the `TreeMap` constructor. Since `BiFunction` is not a `Comparator`, nor a subclass of it, the compiler does not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Because It expects the Comparator and you have supplied the BiFunction.
From Oracle Docs :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T>
```

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such as Collections.sort or Arrays.sort) to allow precise control over the sort order. Comparators can also be used to control the order of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps), or to provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a natural ordering.